# Setting default values in a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I would like to set a default value in a form control as soon as the modal dialog opens, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be that easy. At the moment I don't know why it doesn't set any values.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Modal - Create -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="add_new_task_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add item</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <ul class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="errors.length > 0">
                        <li ng-repeat="error in errors">
                            {{ error }}
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                        <input ng-model="task.quantity" type="text" id="quantity" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="item">Item</label>
                        <input ng-model="task.item" type="text" id="item" class="form-control autocomplete"/>
                    </div>                   

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTask()">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $('#add_new_task_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
            $('#quantity').val("some default value");
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try modal event "shown.bs.modal" which occurs when the modal is fully shown (after CSS transitions have completed), instead of show.bs.modal event. Reference Link: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Comment: Thanks for your reply. unfortunately no difference

Comment: Can you create a fiddle & share the link which might be helpful to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid using jquery if you're using angularjs for this. Though it might work, it kind of goes against the whole idea of using angular in the first place.

Instead, you should use the modal dialog's controller to set the initial model state, like this:

```
$scope.task = {
     quantity: 5,
     item: 'test'
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the correct answer. Javascript set the values, but somehow it wasn't too reliable and there were some strange side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','#add_new_task_modal', function () {           
     $('#quantity').val("asd");
})
```